# Rails 4 Link FactoryGirl to PostgresSequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, factory-bot

There is a unique field `number` in the  `controller` table which is created by the `postgres` sequence. The migration looked like this:

```
def self.up
         execute "CREATE SEQUENCE controller_number_seq START WITH 11000000"
         execute "ALTER TABLE controller ALTER COLUMN controller_number SET DEFAULT nextval('controller_number_seq');"
end
```

Whenever i create now a new instance of `Controller` the number gets incremented to the next free value defined by this sequence.

I wonder now how i can *link* my  `:controller` factory to this postgres sequence.
I could create a FactoyGirl sequence like this

```
sequence(:phone){|n| "1100000#{n}"}
```

(which also works only for n<10 otherwise produces false numbers)

but it seems there is a cleaner way since i use the database i should be able to access the postgres sequence directly and assign it to my `:controller` factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the FactoryGirl docs, you can set initial value for a sequence:

> You can also override the initial value:
>
> ```
> factory :user do
>   sequence(:email, 1000) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
> end
> ```

Which makes it for your example just:

```
sequence(:phone, 11000000)
```

I don't think it's a good idea to use a database generator for this purpose. For one you will have to make sure value resets after running tests or example groups. Also generally it is desirable to have tests decoupled from database for performance reasons. If there is no special semantics depending on sequence on the database level, FactoryGirl sequence would do just fine.